# Jasmine testing custom http service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine

I have written an http service for my application and I would like to test it with Jasmine, but honestly it's my first time writing tests and I have really no idea of where to start by, can someone point me to the good direction ?

I have read a lot of tutorials on the basic Jasmine testing, and I get it, but my problem is more "what should I test, what are the usefull tests", and this http service is a perfect example for me to train with.

Below the http service I'd like to test:

```
angular.module('acme.services.http', [
    'config'
])

    .factory('http', function ($q, $http, $cacheFactory, API_BASEPATH) {

        // **********************************************************
        // Initialize
        // **********************************************************

        var cache = $cacheFactory('toip');

        // **********************************************************
        // Public API
        // **********************************************************

        return {
            get: get,
            post: post,
            put: put,
            update: update,
            destroy: destroy,
            flush: flush,
            resource: resource
        };

        // **********************************************************
        // Published methods
        // **********************************************************

        /**
         * Execute a GET http request.
         * @param path
         * @param config
         * @returns {qFactory.Deferred.promise|*}
         */
        function get(path, config) {
            return call('GET', path, null, config).then(extract);
        }

        /**
         * Execute a POST http request.
         * @param path
         * @param data
         * @param config
         * @returns {qFactory.Deferred.promise|*}
         */
        function post(path, data, config) {
            return call('POST', path, data, config).then(extract);
        }

        /**
         * Execute a PUT http request.
         * @param path
         * @param data
         * @param config
         * @returns {qFactory.Deferred.promise|*}
         */
        function put(path, data, config) {
            return call('PUT', path, data, config).then(extract);
        }

        /**
         * Execute an UPDATE http request.
         * @param path
         * @param data
         * @param config
         * @returns {qFactory.Deferred.promise|*}
         */
        function update(path, data, config) {
            return call('PUT', path, data, config).then(extract);
        }

        /**
         * Execute a DESTROY http request
         * @param path
         * @param config
         * @returns {qFactory.Deferred.promise|*}
         */
        function destroy(path, config) {
            return call('DELETE', path, null, config).then(extract);
        }

        /**
         *
         * @param path
         * @param config
         * @returns {qFactory.Deferred.promise|*}
         */
        function resource(path, config) {
            var ext = config.hasOwnProperty('ext') ? '.' + config.ext : '';
            return $http.get(toUrl(path) + ext, config).then(function (result) {
                return result.data;
            });
        }

        /**
         * Flush the HTTP cache.
         * @param {array} keys
         * @returns {*}
         */
        function flush() {
            var keys = angular.isArray(arguments[0]) ? arguments[0] : arguments;

            if (!keys.length) {
                return cache.removeAll();
            }
            angular.forEach(keys, function (path) {
                cache.remove(toUrl(path));
            });
        }

        // **********************************************************
        // Internal methods
        // **********************************************************

        /**
         * Execute an HTTP request and parse the result.
         * @param method
         * @param path
         * @param data
         * @param config
         * @returns {qFactory.Deferred.promise|*}
         */
        function call(method, path, data, config) {
            config = config || {};

            var defer = $q.defer();
            var url = toUrl(path);
            var handleData = (-1 !== ['PUT', 'POST'].indexOf(method));
            var dontCache;

            // don't cache if {cache: false} or if method != GET
            if (('undefined' !== typeof config && config.hasOwnProperty('cache') && false === config['cache']) ||
                (-1 == ['GET'].indexOf(method))) {
                dontCache = true;
            }

            // try to get data from cache
            var result = cache.get(url);

            if (!result || dontCache) {
                // add method & url
                config = angular.extend({
                    method: method,
                    url: url
                }, config);

                // force false here as we'll cache later
                config.cache = false;

                if (handleData && 'undefined' !== typeof data) {
                    config.data = data;
                }

                $http(config)
                    .success(function (result) {
                        if (!dontCache) {
                            cache.put(url, result);
                        }
                        defer.resolve(result);
                    })
                    .error(function (result) {
                        defer.reject(result['errors']);
                    });

            } else {
                defer.resolve(result);
            }

            // if method invoked were PUT/POST or DELETE, remove all cache
            if (-1 !== ['PUT', 'POST', 'DELETE'].indexOf(method)) {
                flush();
            }

            return defer.promise;
        }

        /**
         * Convert a dot notation path to an url.
         * @param path
         * @returns {string}
         */
        function toUrl(path) {
            if ('local:' === path.substring(0, 6)) {
                path = path.substring(6);
                return path.split('.').join('/');
            }

            return API_BASEPATH + '/' + path.split('.').join('/');
        }

        /**
         * Extract the HTTP request response.
         * @param response
         * @returns {*}
         */
        function extract(response) {
            if (false === response.success) {
                return $q.reject(response['errors'][0]);
            }
            return response['payload'];
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I’d check Angular’s [`$httpBackend`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend):

> Fake HTTP backend implementation suitable for unit testing applications that use the $http service.

Answer (score 0):

Writing Unit tests is about verifying that each unit (in this case function) does exactly what it is intended to do. But I am sure you will find a lot of resources on the internet explaining the idea behind unit testing. But to start out i can share some of the thoughts i have when i write tests.

Taking your toURL function as an example you have to ask yourself: "What should this function do if `path` is [...]"

This should include the cases that demonstrate how the function is intended to work, but also those that have the potential to break it. ( I feel like it really helps becoming a better programmer in general if you always think about ways to break your code)

For example: what should happen if you call the function with `null`?

What happens if you call it with an empty string, a number,  or with "local:"?

You don't have to write 100 tests for the function for every possible value of path you can think of. You should rather try to figure out which cases are realistic scenarios (If other people than you are using your function very obscure things become realistic ;) )

Try to write the tests without looking at your function just think about the scenarios and what you want to happen.

For testing the functions that make http calls you will need to mock your calls (assuming you dont want to make an actual call to a server everytime you run your tests)

I hope that you can get some use out of this.

Have fun testing :)